# Is 'FOR XML' (RAW, AUTO, PATH) supported in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

MS SQL Server supports extracting relational data using FOR XML (RAW, AUTO, PATH). Is this feature supported in SQL Azure? If not, has anyone tried workarounds. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I use `FOR XML PATH` and `FOR XML RAW` in SQL Azure with no problems.  Haven't needed to use the `AUTO` option yet.