# Is or is not 'FOR XML' supported in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I tried to verify whether my code using `FOR XML` clause will run on *Azure SQL Database*. So I looked to Microsoft online documents ([FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017))
where I found that it is not supported

[image]

While I was looking for a solution I found: [Is 'FOR XML' (RAW, AUTO, PATH) supported in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851167/is-for-xml-raw-auto-path-supported-in-sql-azure) which states that it is supported. So I made an experiment

```
print @@VERSION
select (select 'aa' FOR XML PATH('tag'),TYPE)
```

with result

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Mar 19 2019 04:06:22 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation


----------------------------------------------
<tag>aa</tag>

(1 row affected)
```

So the question is:
Is there an error in documents or do I read it wrong way or is it supported now and will not be in future?

**Edit (September 2022)**

The page [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) now states that 'FOR XML' is supported in SQL Azure and so the question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd always trust the [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) over the fluffier "how to do things" documentation. The latter seem to fall out of date more regularly and not be revisited in a timely fashion.

On the `FOR Clause` page (linked above) it says it is supported in Azure SQL Database.

> APPLIES TO: ✓ SQL Server (starting with 2008) ✓ Azure SQL Database ✗ Azure SQL Data Warehouse ✗ Parallel Data Warehouse

There are no mentions *within* the page of any Azure specific limitations either.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Please note also [TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

I opened the document [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), it shows that it's supported in Azure SQL Database.
[image]

Azure SQL Database supports FOR JSON and FOR XML. You can get this from many other blogs.

David Browne  has created a Pull Request to update the docs page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-2017) still states  Azure not supported